# Unknown in Gaussian Eliminations

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I saw an interesting while browsing the internet. Is there any expert that may explain the way to solve questions like this?

[image: Questions]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I would consider two cases:

Case $1$: $x_1 \neq 0$. what can you conclude since it is in RREF form.

Case $2$. $x_1 = 0$. I will further consider two cases, $x_2=0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$.

Overall idea is to consider cases and make conclusion from the RREF.

Comment: Did you give yourself a hint on your own question?

Comment: what do you mean? I am dropping a hint to help the OP solve a problem.